# Autoloading a database class within another class?

Tags: php, database, class, constructor, autoload

I have two classes, Database and User. In the Database class I have function to connect to the database. I am wanting to be able to have a connection to the database within the User class. This is what I am currently doing in the User Class:

```
class User {

    function __construct() 
    {
        require_once 'database.class.php';
        $DBH = new Database();
        $DBH->connect();
    }

    function register_user()
    {
        $DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO users VALUES (:username, :password, :forename, :surname)');
        $DBH->execute(array(':username' => 'administrator', ':password' => '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99', ':forename' => 'Richie', ':surname' => 'Jenkins'));
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member
>   function prepare() on a non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about "scope."  `$DBH` is only declared locally in `__construct()`.

Rectifying this is easy.  Simply add

```
class User {
   private $DBH;
```

and wherever you have `$DBH` change to `$this->DBH`.  May help to read about `$this` and member variables as well.

Comment: I receive this error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Database::prepare()

Comment: That means that the `Database` class does not have a method called `prepare()`.  What is its implementation?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why can't I use the PDO prepare function?

Comment: @ritch then you would have to be using PDO

Answer (score 0):

You would need to assign your `$DBH` to a class property to allow access in other class methods.  Right now `$DBH` is local to `__construct()` and can't be used outside of it

```
class User {

    private $dbh;

    public function __construct() {
        ... // your code
        $this->dbh = $DBH;
    }

}
```

Then in other class methods you would call that object with `$this->dbh`.